# How to write a method that returns cosine similarity between two documents

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, cosine-similarity, countvectorizer

I am writing a method that returns cosine similarity between two documents. Using sklearn CountVectorizer()
I have tried

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def doc_cos_similar(doc1:str, doc2:str) -> float:
  vectorizer= CountVectorizer()
  doc1="Good morning"
  doc2="Good evening"
  documents = [doc1, doc2]
  count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
  sparse_matrix = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
  doc_term_matrix = sparse_matrix.todense()
  return doc_term_matrix
```

#input

```
doc1="Good morning"
doc2="Good afternoon"
```

the
output should be 0.60(something alike)

But the output is a

> matrix([[0, 1, 1],
> [1, 1, 0]])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.

`cosine_similarity(doc_term_matrix)` returns

```
array([[1. , 0.5],
       [0.5, 1. ]])
```

So you can use `cosine_similarity(doc_term_matrix)[0][1]` (or [1][0], it doesn't matter since cosine is symmetric).

P.S. you should pass `doc1` and `doc2` as arguments, instead of hard-coding them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# X = input("Enter first string: ").lower()
# Y = input("Enter second string: ").lower()
X ="Good morning! Welcome"
Y ="Good evening! Welcome"

# tokenization
X_list = word_tokenize(X)
Y_list = word_tokenize(Y)

# sw contains the list of stopwords
sw = stopwords.words('english')
l1 =[];l2 =[]

# remove stop words from the string
X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw}
Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw}

# form a set containing keywords of both strings
rvector = X_set.union(Y_set)
for w in rvector:
  if w in X_set: l1.append(1) # create a vector
  else: l1.append(0)
  if w in Y_set: l2.append(1)
  else: l2.append(0)
c = 0

# cosine formula
for i in range(len(rvector)):
  c+= l1[i]*l2[i]
cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5)
print("similarity: ", cosine)
```